# how to travel to next page of the website I have an issue to navigate to next page

Tags: python, selenium

please anyone one help me. I'm trying to navigate a pages but I don't know my code is not working. I got a product details for the 1st page I want to scrape the details for all the pages in the website. below is my code please check for your reference. thanks in advance

below is link for the website
https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?pageSize=60

```
    import xlwt
    from selenium import webdriver
    import re
    import time
    from datetime import date
    class kotsovolosmobiles:
        def __init__(self):
            self.url='https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones?pageSize=60'
            self.country='GR'
            self.currency='euro'
            self.VAT= 'Included'
            self.shipping = 'Available for shipment'
            self.Pre_PromotionPrice ='N/A'
        def kotsovolos(self):
            
            wb = xlwt.Workbook()
            ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
            ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
            ws.write(0,0,"Product_Manufacturer")
            ws.write(0,1,"Product_Url")
            ws.write(0,2,"Product_Price")
            ws.write(0,3,"Product_Model")
            ws.write(0,4,"Memory")
            ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
            ws.write(0,6,"Color")
            ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
            ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
            ws.write(0,9,"Pre-PromotionPrice")
            ws.write(0,10,"Country")
            ws.write(0,11,"Date")
            ws.write(0,12,"Raw_Model")
            wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\kotsovolos.xls")
            driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
            driver.get(self.url)
            today = date.today()
            time.sleep(5)
            cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]')
            cookies.click()
            print("cookies accepted")
            driver.maximize_window() 
            time.sleep(5)
            titles = []
            models = []
            memorys = []
            prod_prices = []
            p_links =[]
            p_colors = []
            while True:
                storage_box = []
                storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="product"]')
                for storage_boxes in storage_box:
                    product_url = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="title"] a').get_attribute('href')
                    print(product_url)
                    p_links.append(product_url)
    
                    p_model = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="title"] a').text
                    print(p_model)
                    models.append(p_model)
    
                    manufacturer1 = p_model.split(" ")
                    print(manufacturer1[0])
                    titles.append(manufacturer1[0])
    
                    memory = []
                    memory = re.findall('\d+ ?[gG][bB]',p_model)
                    print(memory)
                    memory1 = str(memory).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').replace("[]",'').strip()
                    if "," in memory1:
                        arr=memory1.split(",")
                        for str1 in arr:
                            str2=str1.replace("GB", "").replace("gb", "").replace("'", "").strip() 
                            if len(str2)!=1: 
                                memory_str=str1
                                break 
                    elif (memory1 == ""):
                        memory_str ='N/A'
                    else:
                        memory_str=memory1 
                    memory_str = memory_str.replace("'", "").strip() 
                    print(memory_str)
                    memorys.append(memory_str)
    
                    colors= []
                    prod_color = p_model.split(" ")
                    length = len(prod_color)
                    indexcolor = length-3 
                    colors.append(prod_color[indexcolor])
                    color1 = str(colors).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').strip()
                    print(color1)
                    p_colors.append(color1)
    
                    p_price = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('.priceWithVat > .price').text
                    print(p_price)
                    prod_prices.append(p_price)
     
                next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination_next a')
                time.sleep(3)
                next.click()
                print("next page") 
                time.sleep(3)
    
    kotsovolos_gr = kotsovolosmobiles()
    kotsovolos_gr.kotsovolos()
```

Comment: try using `"https://altex.ro/telefoane/cpl/filtru/promotii-3803/promotii/p/"+x` instead of current url string

Comment: that's not working. please help me for the above program

Comment: you changed the whole question, it is not a good practice.